# checkbox selection using xpath technique selenium webdriver with python script

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, checkbox, selection

I want to select the checkbox using python script. following is checkbox details.

```
<input name="ordno" value="1151218005204|N" onclick="checkCheck(5);" type="checkbox">
```

I have already tried below mentioned syntax but couldn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox', @onclick=checkCheck(4)]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//onclick[contains(text(),'checkCheck(5);')]/following-sibling::checkbox").click()
```

Any one help me to get the right checkbox selection.
Thanks in advance

Comment: <input name="ordno" value="1151218005204|N" onclick="checkCheck(5);" type="checkbox">

Comment: does this check-box element enabled? Any errors occurs?

Comment: enabled means?  When i was trying to access this check box using below commands... so error comes like not able to find the element.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox', @onclick=checkCheck(4)]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//onclick[contains(text(),'checkCheck(5);')]/following-sibling::checkbox").click()

Comment: maybe it's not visible at the moment you try to click on it? have you tried add implicitly wait to let page completely load?

Comment: "enabled" means "clickable"

Comment: yes its enabled.. I can check or uncheck this checkbox on webpage..

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @onclick='checkCheck(5);']").click()
```

Works for me